# How to setup Elsa workflow designer in a React Typescript application?

Tags: react-typescript, elsa-workflows

I created a React Typescript application, using the CRA scaffolding.

```bash
npx create-react-app react-app-with-elsa --template typescript
```

Then, I'd like to add Elsa Workflow Designer (without linking the CDN scripts at runtime).

I attempted to follow the instructions provided at https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/installation/installing-elsa-dashboard and https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/installation/installing-elsa-designer, unsuccessfully.

I added `@elsa-workflows/elsa-workflow-designer` with:

```bash
yarn add @elsa-workflows/elsa-workflow-designer
```

but this seems to install a very old version.
Anyway, I didn't manage to go ahead.

**UPDATE**: I also attempted to install `elsa-workflows-studio`, with lot of fancy stuff, but, again, I had no luck:

```bash
yarn add moment @stencil/core monaco-editor @elsa-workflows/elsa-workflows-studio
```

Can a step-by-step recipe be provided?